# Converting plain text email to HTML using a Transport Agent (Exchange 2010)

Tags: exchange-server-2010

I'm trying to convert all outgoing emails that match a certain criteria to HTML formatted email using a Transport Agent on Exchange 2010.  I have the TA correctly wired up; I can't figure out how to change the message content-type.  The closest I've got is this, which just results in a blank email body:

```
 If body.BodyFormat <> BodyFormat.Html Then
    Dim oTextToHTML As New Microsoft.Exchange.Data.TextConverters.TextToHtml()
    Dim html As New ConverterReader(body.GetContentWriteStream(), oTextToHTML)
    newBodyContent = body.GetContentWriteStream()
    oTextToHTML.Convert(html, newBodyContent)
 End If
```

If I comment of these lines or send already HTML formatted email then the message arrives correctly which implies to me that this is source of the problem (and solution).